Incorrect Argument Positioning when Using sys.argv in Python to Pass Command-Line Arguments
I'm doing the Python for Cybersecurity course on Cybrary. This lesson deals with teaching Cybersecurity professionals on how to Pass Arguments. Now according to this syntax, I'm suppose to get argument2 as the 3rd argument but my PowerShell keeps printing Helloworld? Please help
I'm trying to access the 2nd argument = argument2 not helloworld as that is argument 1 and main.py is argument 0 as illustrated in the lesson- https://app.cybrary.it/immersive/18657139/activity/66842
import sys

variable = sys.argv[2]
print(variable)
// desirable output in Shell after typing python3 main.py helloworld argument2 = argument2 not helloworld

import sys
Directly access the second argument
variable = sys.argv[2]
Print the second argument
print(variable)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This code works fine (outputs argument2) when I run it with Python 3.10.

Thank you for your efforts @AlexDuchnowski . Much Appreciated!

I think when you are running this command
 python3 main.py helloworld argument2
you want to get the 2nd argument. In this way
print(sys.argv[2])
As per as I can understand .
I think you are doing it right . when your giving the command to the powershell dont use any extra spaces .
Here ,
sys.argv[0] is main.py
sys.argv[1] is helloworld
sys.argv[2] is argument2

Many Thanks for your effort. I'll try this in future and keep in mind.

welcome @SakhiwoD
